# How to list all existing loggers using python.logging module

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

Is there a way in Python to get a list of all defined loggers?

I mean, does something exist such as `logging.getAllLoggers()` which would return a list of `Logger` objects?

I searched the python.logging documentation but couldn't find such a method.

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31599940

Comment: since python 3.12 there is [logging.getLogger().getChildren()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getChildren)

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Loggers are held in a hierarchy by a `logging.Manager` instance. You can interrogate the  `manager` on the root logger for the loggers it knows about.

```
import logging

loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
```

Calling `getLogger(name)` ensures that any placeholder loggers held by `loggerDict` are fully initialized when they are added to the list.

Comment: In fact, getting the dict of Logger per name is better than simply a list of Logger alone, so `logging.root.manager.loggerDict` was exactly what I was searching for, thank you!

Comment: A small note here is that root logger is not returned by this snippet.

Comment: Anyone has an explanation about why PyCharm's linting warns about this snippet: `Unresolved attribute reference 'manager' for class 'RootLogger'`? I know it can be easily disabled, but still...

Comment: Note you can access the manager from ***any*** logger, i.e. `my_logger.manager is logging.root.manager`. From the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/135098743a0fae0efbcd98e35458e5bc721702e9/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1358): "There is [under normal circumstances] just one Manager instance ..."

Answer (score 40):

If you want to include RootLogger in the list as well, do something similar to:

```
import logging
loggers = [logging.getLogger()]  # get the root logger
loggers = loggers + [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
```

tested on Python 3.7.4

Comment: This was what solved it for me: the missing root logger was the source of all the problems I had.

Answer (score 12):

If you are trying to examine the hierarchy of logging objects, I'd recommend using `logging_tree.printout()`:

```py
import logging_tree

logging_tree.printout()
```

Or, if you want to have the logging tree accessible to your code:

```py
logging_tree.tree()
```

See https://pypi.org/project/logging_tree/ for more info.

Comment: I would have preferred to do it without depending on a third party library, but thank you for the link :)