# Python : How to set logging level for all loggers to INFO

Tags: python, logging

I am using following config

```
import logging


FORMAT = '%(levelname)s: %(asctime)-15s: %(filename)s: %(funcName)s: %(module)s: %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename="/var/log/out.log", level=logging.INFO, format=FORMAT)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger("Customer")
```

And then there some libraries which I have imported. Those Libraries have 
debug logging statements like

```
 LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
 LOGGER.debug('add_timeout: added timeout %s; deadline=%s at %s',
                     timeout_id, deadline, timeout_at)
```

When I run my program it prints debug logs of internal libraries as well.
I want to avoid debug logs at all.

Comment: Unless the library configures its loggers itself (which it should not do, leaving this up to the application) the global logging level set in `logging.basicConfig()` should be respected so there should be no need to set logging levels of library's loggers.

Answer (score 44):

The below code should do the trick.

```
loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
for logger in loggers:
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

The first line returns the list of logs instantiated. The for loop just sets the level to all the logs.

P.S. credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53250066/4696783