# How can I log only my own messages in python

Tags: python, logging

Here is code:

```py
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

But I getting messages from other modules: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNG95.png)
How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your module is using `chardet`. One way to reduce those logs is to set the level of the logger it uses.

```
logging.getLogger('chardet.charsetprober').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: In fact I'm using _bs4, requests, regex and urllib.parse.quote_
Ignoring _chardet_ helped but partially

Comment: you can get a list of loggers as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249304/how-to-get-the-list-all-existing-loggers-using-python-logging-module) and change those that you are not interested in.