# Logging in the Open AI python library

Tags: openai-api

I am using the open-ai python library. How can I enable logging of HTTP request/response/headers for all calls made to open-ai?

I am not able to find anything specific in the API docs.

Comment: Answering my own question. You can set `openai.log='debug'` and that will log the details.

Comment: What if you want to turn OFF logging? openai.log="error" doesn't seem to eliminate INFO logging statements from OpenAI.

Comment: To turn off INFO, instead of enabling INFO for everything, enable info only for the module you care about, i.e., don't do logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, ...). Instead, omit that level param and set the level for your module by writing logging.getLogger(...).setLevel(logging.INFO) for each of module you care about.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to set [logging levels](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels) for specific loggers.

First, find the OpenAI loggers ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249304/how-to-list-all-existing-loggers-using-python-logging-module) on getting loggers):

```py
import logging

loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
openai_loggers = [logger for logger in loggers if logger.name.startswith("openai")]
# [<Logger openai._legacy_response (WARNING)>, <Logger openai (WARNING)>, <Logger openai._response (WARNING)>, <Logger openai._base_client (DEBUG)>]
```

Once you know their name, you can set a custom logging level for each logger. For example:

```py
logging.getLogger("openai._base_client").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Amazing coverage for multiple cases!

Answer (score 0):

Per the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256249/logging-in-the-open-ai-python-library#comment134957820_76256249) from the OP, you can change the log level (at least to debug) by setting the `log` attribute:

```py
import openai

openai.log = "debug"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill, but this provided me excessive and detailed information in logging. Not just openai calls though.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable debug logging [through an environment variable](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/5cfb125acce0e8304d12bdd39b405071021db658/src/openai/_utils/_logs.py#L16):

```bash
export OPENAI_LOG=debug
```

Note that this also enables httpx logging.